# iPhone XCode - How to change title below app icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

What is the best way to rename the app so that the title below the app icon can have spaces but the build files doesn't have spaces. (ie, title is "My Project" and build file is MyProject.app)

I changed PRODUCT_NAME but when I do that the app file also contains spaces.

Renaming all the fields seems to work fine except I can't find EXECUTABLE_NAME which is the default value for "Executable file".

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The field that you have to change is the `Bundle Display Name` (`CFBundleDisplayName` is the raw key name) in the `info.plist` file from `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to 'your desired name'.

Note: `CFBundleDisplayName` is different from `CFBundleName`. `CFBundleDisplayName` is the human visible/marketing name displayed on the device home screen, under the icon etc. While `CFBundleName` is the filename of the IPA and the folder for the app on the file system, 'Whatever' for example would be archived as `Whatever.ipa` and the app would be installed on a device under the folder called `Whatever.app`.

Comment: Damn now that you tell me, it's pretty easy to do. But it took me over an hour trying. Thx Nithin!!!

Comment: Simple solution, thanks! (This should be something editable via itunes connect. So much with ios app development is overly complicated/buried.)

Comment: StudentX: Though a delayed response, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Xcode 6 and in the Info.plist, the key is called Bundle Name and the default is $(PRODUCT_NAME).  You can double click and change the name, you'll be able to verify it.

If you view the source code for the plist, you'll see:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>Change this to the string to display under the icon</string>
```

Comment: In Xcode 6.1.1, the top field in the Info tab is "Bundle name" as you say, but that is not the field to change. The bottom field is "Bundle display name". That is the on you change. Here is a screenshot of Xcode for an app that has changed many times over the years including at least 3 complete rewrites. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz3aoewa71t5tik/Screenshot%202015-04-08%2023.56.41.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

There should really be a caveat here. If you have shell scripts and other things dependent on the original app name, you may be committed to some extensive changes if you pursue the above solution. If you only want to change the display name, and only that, there's a Bundle display name under Info of your target under Custom iOS Target Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit info.plist in Info tab in xCode

[image: change app name in xcode]