# Where can I find and change the setting that specifies the name of the iOS application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I've created an iPhone app project in Xcode and I'd like to change the name that is displayed under the app icon, as well as in alerts, etc.  By default, the name of the app is the same as the name of the project.  How can I change the name of my iOS app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone XCode - How to change title below app icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189823/iphone-xcode-how-to-change-title-below-app-icon)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look for "Bundle display name" inside your application info.plist.

Comment: Found it!  It's called "Product Name" under the Packaging settings.  Thanks!

Comment: The Product Name shouldn't have spaces, but can be as long as you need.  If you want a shorter name (to fit under the icon) with spaces, set the Bundle Display Name instead of the Product Name.