# Change title under app icon for iPhone 6

Tags: ios

I need to change the name that appears below the app icon. I referred to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189996/2376667.

While changing the bundle name does the trick for other iOS devices, it is not working for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.

eg; if the previous bundle name was "MyApplication" and the new bundle name is "My Application", for rest of the devices the title gets shown as "My Application" but for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, it still gets shown as "MyApplication". So I suppose it is not honouring the space that has been inserted. How do I get the changed name to display for iPhone 6?

Comment: Are you using the simulator? Try restarting the simulator and Xcode then see if it fixes it. I hope it wasn't something like that to cause you frustration. You wouldn't be the only one...

Comment: No, restarting the simulator/Xcode did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Changing App Name is pretty straight forward. It has to be the product name.

Go to

> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name

After setting it, Xcode should be the one generating the necessary changes to the other properties.

If you followed the reference given. 
Kindly put back the Bundle Name value to its default ${PRODUCT_NAME}

I've done this numerous time and it always work.

You don't have to but you could reset the simulator just to be sure you're working on a clean state.

Comment: Changing Product name also did not have any effect for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Comment: have you placed any changes on  your other build properties? This solution does the trick if not something is not allowing it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Bundle name` and `Bundle display name` in `Custom iOS Target Properties` in `Info` plist